# Get value for `Position` property from a Delphi TProgressBar class instance using AutoHotkey (ahk)

Tags: autohotkey, delphi

I would like to obtain the current `Position` (progress) property value from `TProgressBar1`, which is a child of `TProgressFrame1` and grandchild of `TPanel1` within a particular `TProgressDlg` Window. `TProgressBar` is a class defined in Delphi, and `TProgressBar1` is a specific instance that AutoHotkey "sees" with its own `HWnd`.

Is it possible to grab the `TProgressBar1.Position` value from an external application with AutoHotkey?

I've tried

```
; AutoHotkey Version: 1.1.22.07 
DetectHiddenWindows, On
SetTitleMatchMode, RegEx
GroupAdd, MyGroup, ahk_exe [partial path of executable], , , ahk_exe explorer.exe ; exclude any explorer windows open to that path.
WinGet, x, List, ahk_group MyGroup
Loop, %x% ; This application has 68-73 windows, most hidden, when it runs
{
    this_id := x%A_Index%
    WinGetTitle wtit, ahk_id %this_id%
    WinGet, clh, ControlListHwnd, ahk_id %this_id% ;%wtit%, %wtxt%
    StringSplit, clh_, clh, `n
    Loop, %clh_0% ; the 0th entry contains the size of the array this loop iteration. Don't want to loop through all in %clh_ as previous iterations may have stored more values at haven't been cleared.
    {
        clh_cur := clh_%A_Index%
        IfEqual, cl_%A_Index%, TProgressBar1
        {
            B := cl_%A_Index% ; TProgressBar1
            C := %B%.Position ; Expecting something like 60 (percent). I could also divide by %B%.Max to make sure what the range is, assuming I could get values  like this.
            MsgBox "%B% is %C% percent complete"
        }
    }
}
return
```

`%C%` comes out blank, whereas `%B%` is indeed `TProgressBar1`

It looks like in native Delphi, this would look something like (from [here](http://delphi.about.com/cs/adptips2004/a/bltip0104_2.htm))

```
 aPB := TProgressBar(FindComponent('Progress')) ;
 curValue := aPB.Position
```

Delphi codeusage doc for the property [link](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/ComCtrls_TProgressBar_Position.html) indicates that something like
`curValue := TProgressBar1.Position` would work

Do I use something like

1. `ComObjGet`? or
2. `TProgressBar1.__Get(Position)`? or
3. `SendMesssage, 0x03E6, clh_%A_Index%,  0x03330600 ;*`? (and/or any of the above with...)
4. `cpy := TProgressBar1.Clone()` first?

[WM_DDE_REQUEST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648998%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) = 0x03E6
`TProgressBar` has a `Properties` value of `Delphi00001514 0x03330600 (53675520)`

I have since tried some iterations of 3 and 4, but I may be doing it wrong, as there's no evidence that the `MyMessageMonitor` (below) is ever called. Here's what I've tried:

```
WM_DDE_INITIATE   := 0x3E0
WM_DDE_TERMINATE:= 0x3E1
WM_DDE_ADVISE   := 0x3E2
WM_DDE_UNADVISE   := 0x3E3
WM_DDE_ACK   := 0x3E4
WM_DDE_DATA   := 0x3E5
WM_DDE_REQUEST   := 0x3E6
WM_DDE_POKE   := 0x3E7
WM_DDE_EXECUTE   := 0x3E8

OnMessage(0x03E05, "MyMessageMonitor") ; WM_DDE_DATA by MSDN's definition
OnMessage(WM_DDE_DATA, "MyMessageMonitor") ; WM_DDE_DATA there's a post "correcting" MSDN's value at bottom, so may as well look for both
OnMessage(0x03E4, "MyMessageMonitor") ; WM_DDE_ACK

...

; IfEqual block innards
        nAppli := DllCall("GlobalAddAtom", "str", [application exe name, minus .exe], "Ushort")
        nDDE_Topic := DllCall("GlobalAddAtom", "str", [application exe name, minus .exe], "Ushort")
        SendMessage, WM_DDE_INITIATE, A_ScriptHwnd, nAppli | nDDE_Topic << 16,,ahk_id %clh_cur%
        B := cl_%A_Index%
        Bh := clh_%A_Index%
        C := %Bh%.Clone()
        D := %C%.__Get("Position")
        E := IsObject(%C%)
        F := %Bh%["Position"]
        SendMessage, 0x03E6, A_ScriptHwnd,  0x03330600, cl_%A_Index%, ahk_id %this_id% ; send WM_DDE_REQUEST from current window to TProgressBar1
        MsgBox "%B% has position value %D% or %F%. %B% an object? %E%" ; brings up box with "TProgressBar1 has position value  or . TProgressBar1 an object? 0"
        DllCall("DeleteAtom", "Ushort", nAppli)
        DllCall("DeleteAtom", "Ushort", nDDE_Topic)
...
OnMessage(0x03E05, "")
OnMessage(0x03E5, "") ; WM_DDE_DATA
OnMessage(WM_DDE_ACK, "") ; 0x03E4
return

MyMessageMonitor(wParam, lParam, msg, hwnd)
{
    MsgBox "w: " . wParam . " l: " . lParam . " msg: " . msg . " hwnd: " . hwnd
    return
}
```